# Customize OpenCsv CsvToBeanBuilder

Tags: numberformatexception, opencsv

How can I intervere in the process of parsing the CSV file? 
What I intend to do is that if certain values have bad format, I want to correct them. In particular, if there is a value of "1.000-" it results in a NumberFormatException because the minus sign is suffixed instead of being prefixed. Hence, in such a case, I want to switch "1.000-" to "-1.000" and let the parser or CsvToBeanBuilder respectively, continue its work.